# Extract data from multiple classes in selenium using java

Tags: java, arrays, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The objective is to extract reviews from E-com website.How should i proceed to extract data from multiple classes using Selenium and then applying a for loop.Do i have to create an xpath with all the classes if yes how the syntax should be.There are few classes which contains data in string format and integers.

[Flipkart Reviews - class details]

class="_2xg6Ul" Brilliant

class="qwjRop" Best camera in smartphone period. Have note 8 and iPhone X also but pixel 2 with single lens beats them hands down

class= "_3LYOAd _3sxSiS" Flipkart Customer

class="_3LYOAd" 29 Nov, 2017

class="_1_BQL8" 142

Comment: Add your code trials and relevant HTML in proper formatting

Answer (score 0):

Based on the very, very limited information you provided, this is what I came up with. You'll have to provide more information like the code you already have as well as the full HTML for each element.

```
  List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body[contains(@class, '_')]"));

//Iterate through list
for(int i =0;i<list.size();i++) {
WebElement review = list.get(i);
System.out.println(review.getText());
}
```

Comment: Below is the code and i want to extract entire reviews from the below link and write it in excel sheet
driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/google-pixel-2-just-black-64-gb/product-reviews/itmfffkj2aggphym?pid=MOBEYEQGRSSNFFMD");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        List<WebElement> radio=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body[contains(@class, '_2xg6Ul')]"));
        for(int i=0;i<radio.size();i++)
        {
         WebElement local_radio=radio.get(i);
         System.out.println(local_radio.getText());}